# How to execute some commands in terminal with php ?

Tags: php

how can I open terminal with a php program and execute some data , then save the results in a .TXT file ?

I couldn't find any useful idea in websites .

Comment: Which environement (Windows, Linux other...)? You have to use the php.exe

Comment: Is google banned in your country.?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Comment: Why do you want php to open a terminal? Why not just having it do the work? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: My goal is to open terminal with php and execute some commands and save the results in a .TXT file . I know I can do it without php .

Answer (score 0):

Just use `exec()` for that:

```
exec('ls -la', $output);
$result = implode("\n", $output);
file_put_contents($result, 'result.txt');
```

You can and schould read on in the PHP manual and check wether your webhost allows to execute shell commands!

Of course you can run everything beside from `ls -la`!

If you want to execute based on user supplied data make sure to escape it properly!